# Adding new data with identical fields to Firebase without overwriting old data? Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So, essentially I'm trying to allow my users to click a button and add each individual username to a document on Firebase. However, `.set()` obviously sets brand new information while `.update()` overwrites the old information. I've tried using `SetOptions(merge: true)` when writing to Firebase, but that hasn't proven effective either.

I would love it if someone could point me in the right direction and/or explain what I'm doing wrong. This is how I'm handling it currently:

```
CollectionReference scatterSignup =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('scatterSignup');

onPressed: () async {
                      scatterUp.name = username;
                      scatterUp.code = userCode;
                      final scatter = scatterSignup.doc(regionUpload).set({
                        'name': scatterUp.name,
                        'code': scatterUp.code,
                      }, SetOptions(merge: true));
                    }),
```

I expected new information to be added without overwriting (which I believe is the function of `merge` unless I'm mistaken?) but that definitely didn't happen.

Essentially, I'm trying to figure out how to have a single document that consists of multiple `name` and `code` fields: one for each user trying to sign up for the list.

Comment: `update` only overwrite the fields you provide.  Are you saying it behaves differently?  Could you edit the question to provide a specific example of what exactly doesn't work the way you expect, explaining your observations?

Comment: The fields are identical, which is the issue. I want each user to be able to interact with the same button, and have their username and userCode updated to the same "regionUpload" document in Firebase.

Essentially I'm trying to aggregate a signup list from users that interact with this specific button, and I don't want to create a collection that lists them as individual documents and have to go through them 1 by 1.

Comment: You can't have more than one of the same field in a document.  You can have a field that's an array of values, and modify that array.  I suggest reviewing the documentation to learn about array modification operations.

Comment: Hey Doug, thanks for the info. That totally solved my problem, I really appreciate it!